# C++ freeing dynamically allocated memory in shared library causing crash

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I have a shared library mod.so and it has a function getptr to return pointer to a dynamically allocated memory.It also has a function Unload which frees the memory which was allocated.
The main program loads this shared library at runtime and gets the pointer from getptr
function but when Unload function is called it gives me Segmentation Fault.

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  void* module = dlopen("mod.so",RTLD_LAZY);
  typedef int*(*func)();
  typedef void(*func1)();
  func f = (func)dlsym(module,"getptr");
  func1 b = (func1)dlsym(module,"Unload");
  int* p = f();
  b();
}
```

**mod.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int*> allocated;
extern "C"
{
  int* getptr()
  {
    int* p = new int;
    *p = 1024;
    allocated.push_back(p);
    return p;
  }
  void Unload()
  {
    for(auto e: allocated)
      delete e;
  }
}
```

The mod.cpp is compiled as:

g++ -shared mod.cpp -o mod.so -fPIC

Comment: `int* Unload()` -- You did not return a value when you're supposed to return an `int*` -- undefined behavior.  Also, your compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: No,that's not the issue the program crashes even if i use void Unload()

Comment: Whether that fixes your problem is irrelevant -- the code was wrong and you can't go further without making that change.

Comment: In `Unload()`, you don’t call `allocated.clear()`. If you use `Unload()` multiple times interleaved by `getptr()`, you may get double-free (or null dereference) errors unless you get rid of pointers you called `delete` on. If you don’t use `Unload()` multiple times, then why isn’t this code in a destructor instead? Why use raw pointers at all? How about `vector<unique_ptr<int>> allocated; ...; allocated.push_back(make_unique<int>(1024))`? That handles your deallocation automatically. Why allocate the `int`s manually? Why not `vector<int> v; ...; return &v.emplace_back(1024);`?

Comment: When it comes to resources and their allocations, it's always a good design choice to create functions in *pairs*: One for creation or allocation, one for destruction or deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

`dlopen("mod.so",RTLD_LAZY)` returns NULL. Try this:

```
void* module = dlopen("./mod.so",RTLD_LAZY);
if (!module) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error in dlopen: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
}
```

Edit: with this modification your code worked for me on Linux/amd64 with gcc-10.2

Mind you, should you call Unload *twice,* it would cause serious problems. Possible fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int*> *allocated= NULL;
extern "C"
{
  int* getptr()
  {
    if (!allocated) allocated= new vector<int *>();
    int* p = new int;
    *p = 1024;
    allocated->push_back(p);
    return p;
  }
  void Unload()
  {
    if (allocated) {
      for(auto e: *allocated)
        delete e;
      delete allocated;
      allocated= NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No,I have checked dlopen() does not return NULL

Comment: Please edit your original post and include and actual [mcve] that shows the problem. (E.g. if you used some LD_LIBRARY_PATH env.var. them please state that.)